# com.esotericsoftware.kryo cross version compatibility

Tags: serialization, java-8, deserialization, java-7, kryo

I have a few apps in data pipeline which use kafka as a queuing system.
If a producer app on java7 using kryo 2.22 produces to a kafka (java7) then would a consumer app on java8 using kryo 4.0 be able do deserialize the data ?

I short data serialization/deserialization compatible across different kryo versions ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, after certain testing and looking up kryo's github docs i found that data serialization/deserialization is NOT compatible across major version changes of kayo library

https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo :: Section Versioning Semantics, Upgrading

```
we increase the major version if serialization compatibility is broken (data serialized with the previous version cannot be deserialized with the new version)
```